# Django get data of object from ManyToManyField form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Hello i created this form :

```
class CartForm(ModelForm):
 class Meta:
     model = Cart
     fields =( 'products',)
```

from theses models :

```
class Product(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField("Titre", max_length=120)
 subtitle = models.CharField("Sous-titre", max_length=250)
 description = models.TextField("Description")
 picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='objects/')
 enabled = models.BooleanField("Activé")

class Cart(models.Model):
 products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
```

and i want to display on my template an list of choice with their data
So i send form from views but i don't find any way to get the products description i only get their names !

here is my view :

```
def home(request):
 categories = Category.objects.annotate(test=Count('product')).filter(test__gt=0)
 # categories = Category.objects.order_by(
 #     'id')
 test = CartForm()
 return render(request, 'boutique.html', {"categories": categories, "test":test})
```

and what i tried in my template :

```
    {% for ee in test.products %}
        {{ ee.description }}    
        <br />    
    {% endfor %}
```

please help me
have a nice day

Comment: Can you show your template and the view?

Comment: @SLDem yes sorry i just updated my post

Comment: I answered, try this solution

Answer (score 0):

Ok so theres a couple issues here:
First of all you actually need to define what is gonna happen when you submit the form, so in your view do this:

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
 categories = Category.objects.annotate(test=Count('product')).filter(test__gt=0)
 if request.method == 'POST':
     test = CartForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
         cart = form.save(commit=False)
         for product in request.POST.getlist('products'):
             cart.add(product)
     else:
         pass
  else:
      form = CartForm()
 return render(request, 'boutique.html', {"categories": categories, "test": test})
```

then in your template you actually have to render the form (test):

**boutique.html**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ test.as_p }}
    <button type="submit"> Add Items </button>
</form>
```

Now you should see the list of products in template.

**edit**

if you want to show a different model field in your form rewrite its `__str__` method like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.description # to show description
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, showing the form isn't the problem, I want to display other data from the object like description or subtitle

Comment: Thanks but that only change the title of the field, i want to get multiple data not just description or title but the two

Comment: then simply do `return str(self.title) + ' ' + str(self.description)` in the method